# Return list containing indices of each element in a vector

Tags: r

I have a vector in R containing repetitive elements

```
a<-c("A","A","A","B","B","C","A")
```

And I would like to know the most efficient way to transform it in a list where each element is the key, and its positions in the original vector are the values:

```
l<-list(A=c(1,2,3,7),B=c(4,5),C=c(6))
l
$A
[1] 1 2 3 7
$B
[1] 4 5
$C
[1] 6
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
split(seq_along(a), a)
# $A
# [1] 1 2 3 7
# 
# $B
# [1] 4 5
# 
# $C
# [1] 6
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
mywhich<-function(x){
    out<-which(a==x)
    return(out)
}
l <- sapply(unique(a), mywhich)
```

Comment: Hm. Why not `mywhich <- function (x) which(a == x)` which does the same in one single expression? For that matter, `mywhich` is specific to `a` so it makes no sense to use a named function here – just use `sapply(unique(a), function (x) which (x == a))`.

Comment: You won't drag me into this religious fight (I have it every day at the Columbia): some people prefer not to use anonymous functions for their own reasons :-)

Comment: In a functional language? Pardon my French but that sounds stupid.

Comment: Two other questionable practices here are 1) the use of a global variable in your function. 2) the use of `sapply` which depending on the inputs won't always return a list (try `a <- LETTERS[1:3]`) unless you add `simplify = FALSE`.

Comment: I agree with flodel. However, Konrad, writing R code exclusively by anonymous functions is the reason why PhD students come to my office crying because they found some bunch of R lines unreadable and unmantainable. If a function does something specific, even only once, it deserves a name.